# finding UMVUE for $\theta_x$/$\theta_y$

Tags: statistical-inference, variance, fisher-information, sufficient-statistics

Let Xi ~ Exp($\theta_x$), Yj ~ Exp($\theta_y$), i = 1; ... ; n1, j = 1;...;n2. Find UMVUE of $\theta_x$/$\theta_y$.

Since $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are compelete sufficient statistic, by using Lehmann-scheffe theorem, UMVUE should be found by solving E($\bar{X}$/$\bar{Y}$), but due to inverse of exponential family, is it possible to find it?

Comment: $\theta_x$/$\theta_x=1$

Comment: @tommik, sorry it is , $\theta_x$/ $\theta_y$

Comment: and what about independence or dependence between X and Y?

Comment: @tommik it didnt mentione, but I think it suppose to be independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming independence between $X_i $ and $Y_j$ the calculation of the following expectation

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\overline{X}_n}{\overline{Y}_m}  \right]$$

(I used $n,m$ instead of $n_1,n_2$ to simplify the notation...)

is very easy being

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\overline{X}_n}{\overline{Y}_m}  \right]=\frac{m}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\Sigma_iX_i}{\Sigma_iY_i}  \right]=\frac{m}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\Sigma_iX_i\cdot\frac{1}{\Sigma_iY_i}  \right]=\frac{m}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\Sigma_iX_i\right]\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{\Sigma_iY_i} \right]$$

and as known

$$\frac{1}{\Sigma_iY_i}\sim \text{Inverse Gamma}$$

Comment: thank you so much, E(1/$\sum Y_i$) = $\theta$ / m-1, if we put it in above formula by considering E[$\sum X_i$] = n$\theta_x$  then we will have m/m-1 [$\sum X_i$][$\sum Y_i$], this suppose to be our UMVUE?

Comment: yes, but  what about marking my answer as accepted? . It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: ya sure, how can I do that? I didn't know about this option, sorry

Comment: Be careful that I didn't check your calculations, but when you calculate the expectation and your estimator is biased...you have to correct the bias.... I think it shoud be $(m-1)/m...$